# Modifying JDK Path for Oracle SQL Developer in Ubuntu

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ubuntu

I have Oracle SQL Developer installed at the following location:

```
/opt/sqldeveloper
```

Every time I run it using the command `./sqldeveloper`, I get the following error from the GUI:

> You are attempting to run with Java 1.6.0_31. Running this product is
>   supported with a minimum Java version of 1.7.0_51 and less than 1.8

I updated the sqldeveloper.conf file with the following paths:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_05
```

and

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_55
```

And despite all that, same error again.

Comment: I have followed the instructions on [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-installing-oracle-java7-on-ubuntu-linux/) and when I type in `java -version`, its now showing as 1.7.0_55. But I still can't run SQL Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I am a bit late with the response, but I had exactly the same issue until this morning.

What I did is changed:
~/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf

FYI:
How I figure it out: 
1. Go to OracleSQLDeveloper -> Help(menu) -> Properties 
2. Find 'java.home'
(For some reason it was pointing to /usr/lib/jdk1.7.0 (ver 1.7.45), even I've changed sqldeveloper.conf)
3. Since I didn't recognized that specific version, I just ran: 
sudo "find / .... -name '*.conf' -exec grep 'jdk1.7.0' ..."

goodluck

Answer (score 1):

Configure Path to Java

SQL-Developer needs to know how to find your Java Developer Kit:

Note: You need to specify /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386 on 32-bit OS installations.

Terminal

cd $HOME

mkdir -p .sqldeveloper

cd $HOME/.sqldeveloper

echo "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk" > jdk

Comment: I have tried this and its not working...Please see rephrased question above for more clarity. Thanks for your help.